# Getting the program "repo"?

Tags: installation, android, git

I'm trying to follow the instructions at http://developer.mips.com/android/android-source-code/ to install an android development environment on my Ubuntu 12 but I'm missing the program `repo`

Could you tell me how I get it enabled?

```
$ repo init -u  git://github.com/MIPS/manifests.git -b mips-ics-mr1.1 -m mips-ics-4.0.4_r1.1m4.xml
No command 'repo' found, did you mean:
 Command 'rep' from package 'rep' (universe)
 Command 'repl' from package 'nmh' (universe)
 Command 'repl' from package 'mailutils-mh' (universe)
repo: command not found
dev@dev-OptiPlex-745:~/mipsandroid$ sudo apt-get install repo
Läser paketlistor... Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd         
Läser tillståndsinformation... Färdig
E: Kunde inte hitta paketet repo
dev@dev-OptiPlex-745:~/mipsandroid$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you will find every information that you need

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

but i suggest to start from the beginning here

http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html